# How to click this element using Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following HTML, which I have to click

```
<button aria-label="Nur Ergebnisse für Inhalte anzeigen" id="ember912" class="search-vertical-filter__filter-item-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view" type="button">
<!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Inhalte
</span>
</button>
```

id is dynamic.

I tried like this

```
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Nur Ergebnisse für Inhalte anzeigen']/button[@class='search-vertical-filter__filter-item-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view' and text()='Nur Ergebnisse für Inhalte anzeigen']"))).click()
```

and like this

```
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "Inhalte")'))).click()
```

and like this

```
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "Inhalte") and @class="artdeco-button__text"]'))).click()
```

but it does not work, I always get TimeoutException

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following xpath to click on the element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Nur Ergebnisse fÃžr Inhalte anzeigen' and contains(.,'Inhalte')]"))).click()
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@aria-label , 'Nur Ergebnisse') and contains(.,'Inhalte')]"))).click()
```

Note: If you get the `timeout exceptions` from above xpath as well then please check if there any `iframe` present on the webpage.